# Converting Char to its Numerical value without using getNumericValue

Tags: java, char, int

Is there any algorithm that could possibly substitute getNumericValue in converting a character to its numerical value such as 'a' = 1 'b' = 2 and so on? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to map 'a' to 'z' to the numbers 1 to 26, you can subtract 'a' and add 1 :

```
char c = 'e';
int nc = c - 'a' + 1; // 5
```

EDIT :

In order to convert all the characters of some input String to integers, you can use an array to store the integer values.

For example :

```
String input = "over";
int[] numbers = input.length();
for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    numbers[i] = input.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Comment: I get it but (dumb question incoming) let's say I have entered "over" (supposed that the program is asking for an input) and stored it in a character array, how will I get the numerical value of this word? meaning o = 19 and so on?

Comment: @REA98 you'll have to create an int array of the length of the input String, calculate the int value for each character of the String, and assign it to that array. Or, if you prefer, you can use a `Map<Character,Integer>` to map a character to an integer.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a simple artithmetic operation

```
char d = 'd';
int numericValue = d - 'a' + 1; // 4
```

---

This will also work since

> `

is the character before `a` in the ASCII table

```
int numericValue = d - '`'; // 4
```

---

### UpperCase / LowerCase

The following works for either lowercase or uppercase characters

```
char d  = 'd';
int numericValue = d - (d > 96 ? '`' : '@');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  int intVal(char character){
  char subtract = 'a';

  int integerValue = (int) character;

  if(integerValue < 97){
    subtract = 'A';
  }

  integerValue = integerValue - (int) subtract + 1;

  return integerValue;
}
```